# Smallest number in a particular part of my list

Tags: python, sorting, min

I have a question about python. I have to sort a list of random numbers in a particular way (it's not allowed to use `sort()`). I'll try to explain:

I have to search for the smallest number, and swap this number with the number at the first position in the list.

Then, I search again for the smallest number, but this time ignore the first number in my list because this one is already sorted. So, I should start searching for the smallest number from the second number (index 1) till the end of the list. The smallest number then found, should be swapped with the second number in the list(so the index 1).

I hope you understand my problem. This is the code I wrote so far, but I get errors and/or the sorting isn't correct.

```
array = random_integers(10,size=10)
my_list = list(array)
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    print my_list
    a = min(my_list[i:len(my_list)])
    b = my_list.index(a)
    my_list[i],my_list[b]=my_list[b],my_list[i]
    print my_list
```

I think there's a problem in my range, and a problem with the

```
a = min(my_list[i:len(my_list)])
```

I want to search for the smallest number, but not in the ENTIRE list how can I do this?

Comment: basically you want to sort a list without using any built in method?

Comment: Yes, i have to sort a list in this particular way without using built in methods..

Comment: have you heard of merge sort? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Comment: This algorithm is called selection sort. It is commonly assigned as an exercise to introduce sorting.

Comment: I would imagine learning merge sort would do no harm.

Comment: @s16h the OP's algorithm finds the smallest item from the unsorted partition, and puts it at the end of the sorted partition. That's a selection sort, not an insertion sort.

Comment: Sounds like `Bubble Sort` to me, except in reverse, i.e. smallest particles sink down instead of large element bubbling up.

Comment: @lvc, yes, I totally meant Selection Sort. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The problem occurs on this line:

```
b = my_list.index(a)
```

since this searches for the first occurrence of `a` in **all** of `my_list`. If the same number occurs twice, then `b` will always correspond to the smallest such index, which might be less than `i`. So you might end up moving a number which has already been sorted.

The obvious thing to try is to slice `my_list` before calling `index`:

```
my_list[i:].index(a)
```

but note that index will return values between `0` and `N-i`. We want numbers between `i` and `N`. So be sure to add `i` to the result:

```
b = my_list[i:].index(a)+i
```

Thus, the easiest way to fix your code as it presently exists is:

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    a = min(my_list[i:])
    b = my_list[i:].index(a)+i
    my_list[i], my_list[b] = my_list[b], my_list[i]
```

but notice that `min` is searching through all the items in `my_list[i:]` and then the call to `index` is traversing the same list a second time. You could find `b` in one traversal like this:

```
    b = min(range(i, N), key=my_list.__getitem__)
```

---

Demo:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.random.random_integers(10,size=10)
my_list = list(array)
N = len(my_list)
for i in range(N):
    b = min(range(i, N), key=my_list.__getitem__)
    my_list[i], my_list[b] = my_list[b], my_list[i]
    print my_list
```

yields

```
[3, 10, 9, 6, 5, 3, 6, 8, 8, 4]
[3, 3, 9, 6, 5, 10, 6, 8, 8, 4]
[3, 3, 4, 6, 5, 10, 6, 8, 8, 9]
[3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 6, 8, 8, 9]
[3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 6, 8, 8, 9]
[3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 10, 8, 8, 9]
[3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 10, 8, 9]
[3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 10, 9]
[3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 9, 10]
[3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Note that there's no need to keep using `len(my_list)` (or `N`) - `my_list[i:]` defaults to ending at the end of the list.

Comment: If you are going to use numpy then why not use `.argmin()`?

Comment: @Scorpion_God: I don't know if the OP really wants a NumPy-centric solution. He is, after all, implementing selection sort. So I only used numpy here to find a meaning for the OP's `random_integers(10,size=10)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the smallest number from a list you can use `min()`. If you want a part of a list you can use list slicing: `my_list[1:]`. Put the two together and you get the smallest number from a part of your list. However, you don't need to do this, as you can `.pop()` from the list instead.

```
sorted_list = []
while my_list:
    n = min(my_list)
    sorted_list.append(my_list.pop(my_list.index(n)))
```

If you're using numpy arrays then instead of `my_list.index(min(my_list))` you can use the `.argmin()` method.

---

While this type of sorting is good for an introduction, it is not very efficient. You may want to consider looking at the merge sort, and also the Python's built-in timsort.